# O que o comando npm build faz?

Tags: node.js, npm

Não tenho grande conhecimento sobre Node, porém entendo que o `npm` é um gerenciador de pacotes para node.

Até onde vai minha visão com `npm` posso baixar os pacotes do projeto de forma mais prática, posso hospedar meu projeto de forma mais simples, não necessitando, por exemplo enviar todas as dependências para o GitHub. A questão é que não compreendo o comando `npm build`.

- o que esse comando faz?
- o que esse comando produz como resultado do processamento?
- e porque ele é necessário?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## O arquivo `package.json`:

Todos os projetos Node que utilizam algum gerenciador de pacotes, como o [NPM](https://npmjs.org) ou o [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com) possuem um arquivo `package.json`, que define as métricas, de maneira geral, do projeto, identificando as dependências, nome do pacote, e muitas outras informações.

> Para saber mais sobre o arquivo `package.json` e todos as suas funcionalidades, queira consultar a [documentação do `package.json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).

## Os *npm scripts*:

Uma das funcionalidades que gerenciadores de pacotes como NPM ou Yarn fornecem são os *scripts*, que consistem, basicamente, em "*atalhos*" para comandos, definidos no arquivo `package.json`. Eles também fornecem *hooks* para o ciclo de vida do pacote.

Um exemplo (arquivo `package.json`):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  }
}
```

Note que acima definimos o script `start`, que pode ser invocado pelo seu terminal usando `npm run start`, ou, em sua forma reduzida `npm start`.

## O comando `npm build`:

Como demonstrado acima, o autor de um pacote pode definir *scripts* customizados para o seu pacote. Imagine agora que este pacote precise de uma etapa de *build*. Essa necessidade é muito comum em projetos que usam recursos como o [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org).

#### Um exemplo:

Tendo em vista que o pacote não pode ser publicado ao registro do NPM com código TypeScript, é muito comum criar um script (geralmente, por convenção, com o nome `build`), para fazer o `build` do código TypeScript para JavaScript:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc" <-- Comando usado para compilar arquivos TypeScript em JS!
  }
}
```

Este foi só um dos exemplos para o `npm build`, já que o seu uso varia de acordo com o projeto.

## Leitura extra

- https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json
- https://css-tricks.com/why-npm-scripts/

Comment: Excelente resposta, obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

## npm build

Executa o que está especificado no arquivo `package.json`.

[Fonte.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build.html)

Comment: Ao executa-lo ele utilizou-se de três arquivos js e gerou apenas um js minify, como esse fato cabe na explicação dada ? Obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Você esta executando em qual tipo de projeto? E como esta o seu arquivo package.json?

Comment: **Você esta executando em qual tipo de projeto?** Não sei ao certo como responder esta pergunta, porém estou executando o comando `npm build` sob este [projeto](https://github.com/h5p/h5p-drag-question)

Comment: neste caso ele vai executar o comando "webpack -p", que esta especificado no package.json.

Comment: https://github.com/h5p/h5p-drag-question/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Fiz a tradução errada, vou editar a resposta

Comment: Era mais simples que eu pensei, fiz a edição corrigindo o meu erro.