# Como funciona o comando "npm run proxy" do node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy

Quero realizar um trabalho sobre o jogo de código aberto **CodeCombat** (https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat). Eu consegui realizar a instalação do jogo, mas na comunidade (em inglês) me recomendaram executar o comando **"npm run proxy"** para ver o projeto funcionando no navegador.

Quando eu executo esse comando e acesso o endereço *127.0.0.1:3000* no navegador sou redirecionado para o servidor de produção (https://codecombat.com/). Alguns desenvolvedores falaram que "o modo proxy significa que todo o *backend* é o original, somente a *frontend* é o meu".

Eu abri o package.json e nele tem o seguinte conteúdo:

```
  (...)"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./index.js",
    "test": "COCO_TRAVIS_TEST=1 npm run webpack && ./node_modules/.bin/karma start --single-run --reporters dots",
    "test-china": "COCO_CHINA_INFRASTRUCTURE=true npm run test",
    "predeploy": "echo Starting deployment--hold onto your butts.; echo Skipping webpack build --production",
    "postdeploy": "echo Deployed. Unclench.",
    "postinstall": "bower install && node ./runWebpack.js",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "bower": "bower",
    "dev": "webpack --watch",
    "dev-container": "DEV_CONTAINER=1 webpack --watch",
    "multicore": "coffee multicore.coffee",
    "proxy": "COCO_PROXY='true' nodemon",
    "proxy-win": "cross-env COCO_PROXY='true' nodemon",
    "analyzer": "COCO_ANALYZER_BUNDLE=1 webpack --profile --json > stats.json"
  },(...)
```

Pode-se observar que o comando **proxy** tem relação com **COCO_PROXY** (imagino que seja uma variável de ambiente) e o **nodemon**.

Mas como isso funciona? Alguém pode me explicar como funciona esse serviço de proxy no node?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [O que o comando npm build faz?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/354139/o-que-o-comando-npm-build-faz)

Comment: Acredito que não Luiz Felipe, eu abri o arquivo package.json do projeto, e encontrei isso:   "scripts": { (...), "proxy": "COCO_PROXY='true' nodemon"}. Aparentemente esse o comando PROXY está relacionado com COCO_PROXY.

Comment: npm start nao funciona?

Comment: "npm start" funciona Francisco, mas eu não consigo ter acesso completo a plataforma, o material de leitura (https://github.com/codecombat/codecombat/wiki/Dev-Setup:-General-Information) recomenda "npm run proxy" para ter acesso a todos os dados do servidor remoto.

Comment: COCO_PROXY é uma variável de ambiente, da forma que esta é para realizar o start em em linux definindo a variavel, no windows você deve usar o comando `set COCO_PROXY = true` e depois der o start no app.